# Twisted cubic in a singular hyperplane section of a cubic threefold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

It is a continue of the previous question [twisted cubic in a hyperplane section of a cubic threefold](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436029/twisted-cubic-in-a-hyperplane-section-of-a-cubic-threefold). Let $X$ be a complex smooth cubic threefold and $C$ be a smooth twisted cubic, then $C\subset Y\subset X$ for a unique cubic surface $Y$ in $X$.

When $Y$ is smooth, we have 27 lines of second type on $Y$: one has $$\operatorname{Ext}^1(\mathcal{O}_L(-1),\mathcal{O}_L(1))=0$$
and
$$0\rightarrow\mathcal{N}_{L/Y}=\mathcal{O}_L(-1)\rightarrow\mathcal{N}_{L/X}\rightarrow\mathcal{N}_{X/Y}|_L=\mathcal{O}_L(1)\rightarrow0$$
The twisted cubic $C$ misses 6 of them, intersects 15 of them once and 6 of them twice.

What about the lines on a singular hyperplane section $Y$?

Answer (score 0):

Such a hyperplane section is a normal integral cubic surface. Such cubic surfaces are classified by Bruce and C. T. C. Wall in [On the Classification of Cubic Surfaces](https://doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s2-19.2.245).

Comment: If this satisfactorily answers your question, then don't forget to accept it.